# How to get page number from item name in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am working with Oracle Apex.
I'm trying to get page number from an item name like `P11_USER_NAME`
but, if I use `substr` function, then it's returning an error *invalid number*.

I hope to find any easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know (or don't; doesn't matter), item name doesn't **have to** contain page number. That's what most of us do because it is simpler for us, developers and because documentation suggests so. It means that - presuming this is page "1" - item name can be

- `P1_ID` (you expect "1" as result here, which would be OK), or
- `ID` (no page number here at all), or
- `MY_ID` (no page number here either), or
- `P123_ID` (you'd get "123" as result, but - that's page 1, not page 123 so you'd get wrong result), or ...

Therefore, I believe that you should actually query `apex_application_page_items`, pass certain information to it (e.g. workspace name, application ID, **item name** or whatever you want) and get the **correct result**, regardless of whether item name contains page number or not.

For example:

```
SQL> select i.page_id
  2  from apex_application_page_items i
  3  where i.application_id = 120
  4    and i.item_name = 'P121_EVBR';

   PAGE_ID
----------
       121

SQL>
```

(Query `apex_application_page_items` to see all information it offers.)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` here with a capture group:

```sql
SELECT name, REGEXP_SUBSTR(name, '^P([0-9]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS page_no
FROM yourTable;
```